# Angular JS Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-google-maps

I'm using [angularjs-google-maps](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) and am getting an error when trying to loop over my customers as markers on a map.

```
<map>
  <custom-marker ng-repeat="cust in customers" position="[ {{ cust.lat }}, {{ cust.lon }} ]">
    <div class="{{ cust.category }}">{{ cust.name }}</div>
  </custom-marker>
</map>
```

The error seems to have something to do with `cust.category` and `cust.name`, as when I remove these they work fine.

This is the first couple lines of the error message I'm getting:

```
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["[ cust.category , cust.name ]; newVal:
[\"pro\",\"Fred\"]; oldVal: [\"pro\",\"Fred\"]","fn: function (context) {\n          
try {\n for(var i = 0, ii = length, part; i<ii; i++) {\n
```

Full error message [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=gTaKHTJ6).

Any help with this is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Code for the custom-marker directive that's part of angular-google-maps is [here](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/blob/master/directives/custom-marker.js).

Comment: @realpha, could you please show your data? What is the data type of `cust.category`?

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle of your issue?

Comment: @AbhilashPA `cust.category` is a string, as is `cust.name`. Both exist inside an object.

Comment: can you provide sample plunkr?

Comment: Looks like the watcher is on every variable used within the custom-marker directive, so each variable as it gets set would grow something crazy especially on initialization.   You may want to add a timeout to delay the setup till initialization completes, see if that keeps the watcher happy.

Comment: I believe, that `scope.$watch('[' + varsToWatch.join(',') + ']'` is an issue. Need set third `$watch` parameter to `true`, for compare recreated arrays.

Comment: Can you provide the code for your controller?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the digest cycle is stuck in a loop. Angular has a digest cycle where they watch models (whatever is on $scope) and apply changes to the views if the models change. If in a digest cycle you're executing some function that changes a value again, you're triggering another digest cycle which triggers that same function again, changes a value on the model and triggers an infinite loop of digest cycles.

That said, you might want to add the code for your customMarker directive for answers to be more precise.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure why that would be happening. I've updated my question with a link to the custom-marker directive code from the angular-google-maps repo.

Comment: Per the docs, this appears to be the correct answer to the question of 'why is this error being thrown?' https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest

Answer (score 0):

why are you binding class="{{ cust.category }}",try using ng-class.Also can you use track by $index in ng-repeat.I was getting this error when running my ionic app on ios9.They released a patch to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Code like this:

```
scope.$watch('[' + varsToWatch.join(',') + ']'...
```

looks like `"[obj1.prop, obj2.prop]"` after concatenation.
Expressions, like this parsed by `$parse` and cause to evaluate self to new instance of array every iteration, even if nothing changed inside.

You should interpolate/parse it before call `$watch` and write a condition, which changes only than related data really was changed.

---

`$watch` is a `function(watchExp, listener, objectEquality, prettyPrintExpression)`
You can try to use third parameter(`objectEquality`) to compare arrays by value, but not by reference equality.

```
@param {boolean=} objectEquality Compare for object equality using {@link angular.equals} instead of comparing for reference equality.
```